# proper use of the ternary operator in a function strToInt (C)

Tags: c, operator-keyword, ternary

```
for (minus == false ? i = 0 : i = 1; string[i] >= '0' && string[i] <= '9'; ++i)
    {
        intValue = string[i] - '0';

        minus == false ? result = result * 10 + intValue : 
            result = result * 10 - intValue;

    }
```

> error: expression is not assignable
>   screenshot - http://share.pho.to/AarcJ

https://codeshare.io/5Pdd7X

Comment: I suggest you do something like `i = minus == false ? 0 : 1` instead. Change both instances you have.

Comment: You want `i = (minus == false) ? 0 : 1` or simply `i = (minus != false)`

Comment: Or this. `i = !!minus`

Comment: Or , of course `i=minus`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use (for example)

```
for (i = minus? 1:0; string[i].... etc
```

And...

```
result = result * 10 + minus? (-lastvalue) : lastvalue;
```

Comment: result = result * 10 +  minus ? (-intValue) : intValue;  http://share.pho.to/AarrP

Comment: :) I've fixed it.                                                                                                                    result = result * 10 +  (minus ? -intValue : intValue);

Answer (score 2):

`minus == false ? i = 0 : i = 1` will be parsed as `(minus == false ? i = 0 : i) = 1` because of operator precedence rule. After evaluation of `minus == false ? i = 0 : i`, left side of operator `=` will become an rvalue, but assignment operator must have an lvalue as its left operand.
Change it to `minus == false ? (i = 0) : (i = 1)`